# Sending emails with attachments using Ruby on Rails via SendGrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I am trying to send email with attachments using Ruby on Rails.
I followed the instructions from [the ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) site.

```
def welcome(recipient)
  @account = recipient
  attachments['file.csv'] = File.read('/path/to/users.csv')
  mail(:to => recipient,    
       :bcc => ["email@example.com", "email2@example.com"],
       :subject => "Sending attachment")
end
```

I am able to receive emails but without the attachment, I am trying to attach csv file but I am getting a file called "noname" as attachment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had this problem. I was not providing a body for the email, and was sending the attachment only. Unfortunately, it appears that SendGrid gets confused by this, sending an empty email (which is expected) with an empty attachment (which is neither expected nor desired).

Therefore, **the solution**: provide a body for the email. In your specific case, an `/app/views/application_mailer/welcome.text.erb` template with a simple text, saying "See attached" or whatever appropriate.

Comment: FYI this happens when using ActionMailer without SendGrid as well.

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid is an SMTP service, and thus should function just as any other outbound SMTP service.  Are you sure your syntax and filepaths are correct?

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome(recipient)
    attachments['free_book.pdf'] = File.read('path/to/file.pdf')
    mail(:to => recipient, :subject => "New account information")
  end
end
```

1. Verify correct syntax
2. Verify correct filepath
3. Verify permissions on file are set correctly
4. Check your logs

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, I just cross checked all the things which u  mentioned. Every thing looks clear but I am not receiving the desired attachments instead I am getting " noname" as attachment.

Comment: :Hello thanks for the reply, I just cross checked all the things which u mentioned. Every thing looks clear but I am not receiving the desired attachments instead I am getting " noname" as attachment